# Keeping DRY with custom Django templatetags

Tags: python, django, dry, django-templates

I have an existing templatetag, `show_next_event`:

```
def show_next_event():
    try:
        e = Event.objects.filter(published='1').order_by('date').filter(date__gte=datetime.date.today())[0]
    except IndexError:
        e = ''
    return {'event': e}
register.inclusion_tag('events/next_event.html')(show_next_event)
```

I'd like to abstract the template. First thing that comes to mind is to change `show_next_event` to just `next_event` and then add two new functions; `show_next_event` and `show_next_event_badge`. Im hoping I can do something like the following but it doesn't work as-is:

```
def next_event():
    try:
        e = Event.objects.filter(published='1').order_by('date').filter(date__gte=datetime.date.today())[0]
    except IndexError:
        e = ''
    return {'event': e}

def show_next_event():
    next_event
register.inclusion_tag('events/next_event.html')(show_next_event)


def show_next_event_badge():
    next_event
register.inclusion_tag('events/next_event_badge.html')(show_next_event_badge)
```

Or is there an even better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django is Python, not Ruby. You can't call a function just by specifying its name: you need to use the calling parentheses. And Python doesn't automatically return the value of the last expression in the function: you need to use the `return` statement.

So, this should work:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('events/next_event_badge.html')
def show_next_event_badge():
    return next_event()
```

Also, note that I've used the decorator syntax to register the tag.

Comment: What modules are required to import to use the decorator? I like that approach!

Comment: You don't need to import anything else.

Answer (score 1):

After following @Daniel suggestions, you could do this to avoid the `def`s (DRY!) :

```
show_next_event = next_event
show_next_event_badge = next_event
```

**EDIT:**

It would be like this:

```
def next_event():
    try:
        e = Event.objects.filter(published='1').order_by('date').filter(date__gte=datetime.date.today())[0]
    except IndexError:
        e = ''
    return {'event': e}

show_next_event = next_event
show_next_event_badge = next_event

register.inclusion_tag('events/next_event.html')(show_next_event)
register.inclusion_tag('events/next_event_badge.html')(show_next_event_badge)
```

Comment: Hrm, maybe im doing this wrong. Can you edit your answer and supply a snippet?